# ValueError: could not convert string to float:'Petal.Length' (machine learning example)

Tags: python

I am running the example code from below link to create a model and validating with iris data set.

http://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/

In the above link, they used online dataset and it is working fine.

I have downloaded iris dataset in a csv format and ran the same program in linux box, but it throws the following error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nn/Desktop/iris.py", line 44, in <module>
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 140, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv_iter)
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 608, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 571, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 109, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 238, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1173, in fit
    order="C")
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/home/nn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Petal.Length'`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if when you are reading the data using read_csv are you ignoring the header?
You can use in **read_csv**:

```
header='infer'
```